# Visual studio, Download file on Debug

Tags: vsto, visual-studio-debugging

I'm working on a VSTO excel addin.
When debugging the solution we automatically open an Excel file located in the solution.

The working version of this file is hosted on a corporate sharepoint.
I would like to update the solution version with the sharepoint version each time I launch a debug on my local machine.

But I really don't know where to start. Is there a way to execute a powershell script on debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Build Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx). We'are using Post-build for copying a file from one folder to another - something like

> xcopy "$(ProjectDir)\$(OutDir)file.dll"
>   "$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName)\Folder*.*" /R /Y

So every time you build your project, it will get the latest from SharePoint to your project folder and then you start debugging